# ¿Por qué no puedo usar parámetros con axios en peticiones post y get?

Tags: javascript, express, axios

Tengo la siguiente petición con **axios**:

```
axios.post(`${baseURL}/test/updateInProcess/`, {
    params:{
        id: _id
    }
});
```

Pero cuando mi API con Express y Mongoose recibe la petición siempre manda undefined en ese id, aquí lo recibo:

```
exports.updateInProcess = (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.query;
    console.log('id: ' + id);
}
```

Salida:

> id: undefined

Cuando hago la petición con los parámetros en Postman si funcionan el `req.query`. Cuando lo hago con **axios** la solicitud se lleva a cabo pero no hace lo que debería porque manda `undefined`.

Comment: cuando pones los `params` en postman lo haces en `Params` o `Body`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque estás enviado en el post un objeto así

```
{
    params:{
        id: _id
    }
}
```

Y en backend estás intentando leer el objeto cómo si fuera así

```
{

    id: _id

}
```

Me imagino que intentas usar `params` cómo se usa en una petición `get` de **axios**, pero en post, el objeto que pones como segundo parámetro de la función **post** son directamente lo que vas a enviar a la api, por lo tanto lo que estás enviando es un objeto como el primero que te cité y deberías enviar uno cómo el segundo.

Así:

```
axios.post(`${baseURL}/test/updateInProcess/`, {

    id: _id

});
```

Comment: Tiene sentido para mí, es lo que pensaba, pero no hay mucha claridad en al documentación. Gracias,